# Movable inline toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am working on a currently publicly closed presentation editor, that uses CKE for it's content WYSIWYG manipulation.

Multiple times we have recieved the same feedback ticket - the editor toolbar sometimes obstructs near elements, hence disturbing the preview and that it'd be awesome if the toolbar could be absolutely draggable around.

Is there a way to make CKEditor's 4.x [inline toolbar](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline) draggable / movable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [shared spaces](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.1.1/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html) plugin to put toolbar in chosen container and then add some D&D handler to that container.

Answer (score 1):

CKeditor with JQuery and JQueryUI posible following solution:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
        $(".cke").draggable();
});
```

If you don`t want use JQuery UI, you can use [drags "plugin" from css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)

code:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
        $(".cke").drags();
});
```